# Change the search icon in twenty fourteen

Tags: css, search, icon

I guess the title says all. I'm trying to change the search icon of the twenty fourteen theme, because I need a darker one.

I tried like this:

```
.search-toggle {
        background: url('http://www.citizen-science.at/wordpress/wp-content/themes/cs/img/search-icon.png');
    }
```

which results in nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is more of a simple CSS question than actually related to WordPress.

However, you need to change your `style.css`. As TwentyFourteen does not use images, but pseudo css-classes, you need to change this as well:

```
.search-toggle {
    background: #fff url('http://www.citizen-science.at/wordpress/wp-content/themes/cs/img/search-icon.png') no-repeat;
    background-size: 30px;
    background-position: 10px;
}
.search-toggle:before {
    content: "";
}
```

By the way, your background image is huge. Try providing a smaller one.

Answer (score 0):

Aside from TwentyFourteen, like Storefront,I had to use this. Since this thread is appearing in the top search. I have to place my code in here.

```
.widget_product_search form::before{
    color:#c26c5e !important;
}
```

Comment: That won't change the icon, will it, but it will change the fill colour for all SVGs on the page? is that really what you meant to do?

Comment: I just give a head start, it should be drill down to the component that one might want to style. I just want to give the information that, that magnifier icon is actually an svg. :)

Comment: I edited my answer. Thank you bro Rup.